# AJAX: Add <li>s to existing

Tags: javascript, ajax, appendchild

I'm trying to add `<li>`s to an existing `<ul>` with AJAX. It is a very simple test.

HTML:

```
<ul id="full_list">
    <li>Existing item 1</li>
    <li>Existing item 2</li>
    <li>Existing item 3</li>
    <li>Existing item 4</li>
    <li>Existing item 5</li>
</ul>
<button type="button" onclick="addMoreItems()"></button>
```

JS:

```
function addMoreItems () {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("full_list").appendChild = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "filler.txt", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

filler.txt:

```
<li>New item 6</li>
<li>New item 7</li>
<li>New item 8</li>
<li>New item 9</li>
<li>New item 10</li>
```

Desired result:

```
<ul id="full_list">
    <li>Existing item 1</li>
    <li>Existing item 2</li>
    <li>Existing item 3</li>
    <li>Existing item 4</li>
    <li>Existing item 5</li>
    <li>New item 6</li>
    <li>New item 7</li>
    <li>New item 8</li>
    <li>New item 9</li>
    <li>New item 10</li>
</ul>
<button type="button" onclick="addMoreItems()"></button>
```

I have no problems populating the `<ul>` with `filler.txt`'s `<li>`s if I use `innerHTML`. I have spent time searching this and other sites, and have seen it said that unlike `innerHTML` which replaces all of an element node's contents, `appendChild` expects an object as opposed to a string, and so can't be added to the DOM after the page has loaded.

Unfortunately I'm still not able to figure out how to append a text string with a lot of `<li>`s back-to-back to the existing `<ul>`. Thoughts?

(The `filler.txt` document in `xmlhttp.open()`'s second parameter is something I'm only using for testing purposes. Once I figure out how to append more `<li>`s into the `<ul>` with AJAX, I'll use a PHP page instead which generates the `<li>`s with information from my MySQL db.)

Comment: What is the problem with `.innerHTML += responseText` ?

Comment: Deleted my answer as I didn't notice there was no jQuery tag. as @Abhitalks saus. what's wrong with `.innerHtml += ...`?

Comment: @Abhitalks This works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @d_ominic I never thought to try that, and I forgot to mention that I wasn't using jQuery. But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the output:

var newItems = "

New item 6

New item 7

New item 8

New item 9

New item 10

";

```
        document.getElementById("full_list").innerHTML += newItems;
```

For simplicity, I used a variable already with html and added in innerHTML property.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use appendChild(), rather than `.innerHtml += ...` try it like this:

```
var element = document.createElement("li");
var elementContent = document.createTextNode(xmlhttp.responseText);

element.appendChild(elementContent);
document.getElementById("full_list").appendChild(element);
```

Comment: Looks like it's just taking all my `<li>`s in `filler.txt` and wrapping them inside the `<li>` that `createElement()` creates. So it just outputs `<li>New item 6</li><li>New item 7</li><li>New item 8</li><li>New item 9</li><li>New item 10</li>` (displayed on the screen) which are in a single `<li>` tag.

Is there a way to use `appendChild()` for multiple `<li>`s, then?

Comment: I'm not sure how your `xmlhttp.responseText` looks. so you'll need to experiment. Maybe try iterating through your text and create a new `li` element before appending it. Also, don't have `"<li>"` as strings in your response text.